# Why does my code seem to switch to the GET method instead of proceeding with the POST script

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create the registration page on a website using Flask + SQLite
But instead of inserting data into my database, I just have the html page that gets loaded and nothing that gets done.
Here is what I get in the console:
[image: Picture of my console log]

(ends at "checked username successfully" and then loads "register.html" again)

Here is my code:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():

    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            username = request.form["username"]
            password = request.form["password"]
            confirmation = request.form["confirmation"]
            # Check if username does not already exist
            with sqlite3.connect("flashcards.db") as con:
                check = con.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)
                checked = check.fetchone()
                print(checked) 
                print(bcolors.OK + "Checked username successfully" + bcolors.RESET)
                
                if len(checked) != 0:
                    print(bcolors.OK + "if len(checked) != 0" + bcolors.RESET)
                    message = "This username is already taken"
                    return redirect("/register", message=message)

                if password == confirmation and username:
                    print(bcolors.OK + "if password == confirmation and username" + bcolors.RESET)
                    insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (username, hashed_password) VALUES(?, ?)"
                    values = (username, generate_password_hash(password, method="pbkdf2:sha256", salt_length=8))
                    cur = con.cursor()
                    cur.execute(insert_query, values)
                    con.commit()
                    print(bcolors.OK + "Data inserted successfully" + bcolors.RESET)
                    return redirect("/login")
                else:
                    print(bcolors.OK + "In the else" + bcolors.RESET)
                    return redirect("/register")
        except:
            con = sqlite3.connect("flashcards.db")
            con.rollback()

    return render_template("register.html")
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus="ON" autocomplete="OFF">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="OFF">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm your password" autocomplete="OFF">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a link to `/register` on the `/` page?

Comment: What's the name of the page that has the form on it?

Comment: I think maybe an error occurs in or after checked username successfully print statement which then goes to except part and then it again render register.html. try printing something in except statement.

Comment: Looking at where that `print` statement is in your code and what comes after, I'm guessing it throws an exception - which you swallow without logging anything, just rolling back the database and returning the rendered HTML. Perhaps the [fetchone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) call doesn't return anything? (And if it does, I am not sure if the "sequence" that it returns will be something you can call `len` on.)

Comment: In fact I'm being dense - you can SEE in your console that `checked` is `None`, so of course calling `len` on that throws an exception!

Comment: @Barmar Yes on the main page I can go to the register page, the form is on the register page

Comment: @charchit You're right it then goes into the except part!

Comment: The GET request is from when the user initially opened the register page to get the form.

Comment: When you click on a link it uses a `GET` request.

Comment: Note that the context manager will commit or rollback the insertion as necessary; you don't need to call `commit` or `rollback` explicitly. That may get rid of the need to catch any exception at all.

Comment: Also, the `except` block creates a new connection, so it's not rolling back the original transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may lie with your `if len(checked) != 0:` code.  Can you change that line to `if check is not None`?

Comment: What does this have to to do with the `GET` request that the question asked about?

Comment: `if len(checked) != 0:` throws an error which is caught by the `try...except`. After the `except` block is handled it will `return render_template("register.html")` which is the behavior OP expects from a `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

**(Not an answer but a trick)**

It's hard to debug for you if you catch all exceptions, so you need community help to debug your program. Change your code as follows:

```
try:
    ...
except BaseException as err:
    print(f"BUG: {err}")
    con = sqlite3.connect("flashcards.db")
    con.rollback()
```

Suggested by @chepner:

In your console, you can see `None` due to `print(checked)` and few lines later, you test `len(checked)`.  You are catching and silently ignoring a TypeError exception from the call to len(None).

Comment: I'd update this to point out that the OP is, in fact, catching a silently ignoring a `TypeError` from the call to `len(None)`.

Comment: Yes with this code I get the error :
"BUG: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

So thanks to you I fixed it with:
"if checked != None:"

Thank you so much!!!